# How do I use a crimson altar in Journey mode?

Tags: terraria-console

Are you able to use one in Journey mode? I have been trying for an hour. Is it because I’m on PS4?

Answer (score 2):

Terraria's altar (or [crafting stations](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Crafting_stations) in general) is a bit unintelligible to use at first glance. As the linked page's description says,

> *Entering the inventory screen displays the "Crafting window" in the lower-left, and when the player is standing near one or more Crafting Stations and possesses the right crafting ingredients, the bar is expanded with additional item choices.*

It's a bit confusing at first - You have to get close to the crafting station, and you also have to have the ingredients of what you want to craft. By the way, Journey mode doesn't restrict access to any crafting station (including crimson altar of course), so you should be able to "use" the crimson altar without any problems, if you have the correct ingredients.